# I can’t figure out what’s wrong with my aloe

Tags: diagnosis

[image]

I’m getting worried about this little plant. It was potted about two weeks ago, I watered it on Sunday (waited about a week after putting before watering the plant). Now the bottom leaves are yellowing, and another higher leaf is starting to yellow and dry out too. How do I save him? I don’t think that at being overwatered because it has only been watered once in two weeks. Checked the base and it looks white and healthy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell for certain from the photos, but it looks like those are the oldest leaves going yellow. When plants are under stress they can give up on older, less productive leaves and drop them, I suspect that is what you are seeing. If the underground parts aren't rotten then I think it's nothing more than a reaction to the repotting stress.

Look for new growth in the center, if its making new leaves you have nothing to worry about (relatively speaking). Give it plenty of sun and water it when it gets dry. If it is fall/winter where you are it may not grow much until spring when the days get longer.

Your pot has drainage holes, right?

Comment: Thanks Tim!! And yes the pot has drainage holes of course and is potted in terra cotta pot. I Know aloe Vera tends to be prone to overwatering so I tried to get something that would aloe good drainage and evaporation. It is fall here now :( hopefully the poor little one will survive winter but I was worried because besides those two bottom leaves there is a third leaf in the picture also starting to become transparent and thin too, but I will try my best to baby it for now. Thanks again :)